# An inequality for a coupled Markov chain

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

Let $X_n$ be a Markov Chain on a finite state space with transition function such that $p(x,y)>0$ for all $x,y \in \Sigma$. Consider the time $T$ for the coupled chain $(X_n, Y_n)$ to reach the diagonal $(a,a): a\in \Sigma$.

Show that for some $0<r<1$, we have $P(T>n+1) \leq rP(T>n)$.

We have that the coupled chain is aperiodic, irreducible, and positive recurrent, so the pointwise Ergodic Theorem applies. We do have that $\tau < \infty$ but I do not know how to show this at all. The only inequality I can locate states that $|P(X_n = y) - P(Y_n = y)| \leq P(T>n)$ and this obviously also holds for $n+1$ but this information is insufficient.

Comment: For some $r,$ or for any $r?$

Comment: Since the time is a random variable, why not call it $T$ instead of $\tau?$ As it is, you haven't defined $T,$ forcing us to guess.

Comment: For some r. And I apologize, it should be P(\tau > n) etc. Tau and T are the same here, my mistake.

Comment: I assume the "coupled chain" defines $\{Y_n\}_{n=0}^{\infty}$ independently but with the same transition probabilities. The fact that you can go from any state to any other state in just one hop means that, wherever $X(n)$ and $Y(n)$ are at time $n$, you always have $Y(n+1)=X(n+1)$ with probability at least some fixed positive value.

Comment: Do not delete a question immediately after getting an answer.  This is disrespectful to the person who took the time to answer your question, and to future readers who might find the answer helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Clearly $$
\mathbb P(T > N+1) = \mathbb P(T>N+1 | T>N) \mathbb P(T>N)
$$
For the conditional expectation, if $T>N$ then $X_N \neq Y_N$, hence we may write $$
\mathbb P(T>N+1 | T>N) = \sum_{x,y \in \Sigma,x \neq y} \mathbb P(T>N+1, X_N = x, Y_N = y|T>N) 
$$
Now, for any three events $A,B,C$,
$$
\mathbb P(A\cap B |C) = \frac{\mathbb P(A \cap B \cap C)}{P(C)} = \frac{\mathbb P(A \cap B \cap C)}{P(B \cap C)} \frac{\mathbb P(B \cap C)}{P(C)} = \mathbb P(A|B \cap C) \mathbb P(B | C)
$$
Using this, $$
P(T>N+1, X_N = x, Y_N = y|T>N) \\= \mathbb P(T>N+1 | X_N=x,Y_N=y,T>N)\mathbb P(X_N=x,Y_N = y|T>N)
$$
Look at the first conditional. Conditioned on $T>N,X_N=x,Y_N = y$, clearly $X_{N+1}\neq Y_{N+1}$ is necessary and sufficient for $T>N+1$. Therefore, $$
\mathbb P(T>N+1 | X_N=x,Y_N=y,T>N) = \sum_{x'\neq y' \in \Sigma} \mathbb P(X_{N+1}=x',Y_{N+1} =y'|X_N=x,Y_N=y,T>N)
$$
which is obviously equal by taking the complement, to $$
\sum_{x'\neq y' \in \Sigma} \mathbb P(X_{N+1}=x',Y_{N+1} =y'|X_N=x,Y_N=y,T>N)\\ = 1-\sum_{a \in \Sigma} \mathbb P(X_{N+1} = a,Y_{N+1}=a|X_N=x,Y_N=y,T>N)
$$
By the Markov property and the property of the coupling,$$
\sum_{a \in \Sigma}\mathbb P(X_{N+1} = a,Y_{N+1}=a|X_N=x,Y_N=y,T>N) = \sum_{a \in \Sigma}p(x,a)p(y,a)
$$
We have thus proven that $$
\mathbb P(T>N+1 | X_N=x,Y_N=y,T>N) = 1 -  \sum_{a \in \Sigma}p(x,a)p(y,a) \leq 1 -r
$$
where $r = \min_{x\neq y \in \Sigma} \sum_{a \in \Sigma} p(x,a)p(y,a)$ is a *positive* number being a minimum of finitely many positive numbers. Furthermore, $r<1$, which I leave the reader to prove by definition of $p$ and $r$. Hence, $0<1-r<1$

Going back,$$
P(T>N+1, X_N = x, Y_N = y|T>N) \\= \mathbb P(T>N+1 | X_N=x,Y_N=y,T>N)\mathbb P(X_N=x,Y_N = y|T>N) \\ \leq (1-r)\mathbb P(X_N=x,Y_N = y|T>N)
$$
Summing over $x\neq y \in \Sigma$,$$
\mathbb P(T>N+1 | T>N) = \sum_{x,y \in \Sigma,x \neq y} \mathbb P(T>N+1, X_N = x, Y_N = y|T>N) \\
\leq (1-r) \sum_{x,y \in \Sigma,x \neq y} \mathbb P(X_N=x,Y_N = y|T>N) \leq (1-r)
$$
Of course, this implies that $\mathbb P(T>N+1) \leq (1-r)\mathbb P(T>N)$, as desired. As a consequence, $\mathbb E[T] < \infty$.